# ElasticBeanstalk server users/groups and `git aws.push`

Tags: linux, git, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When running `git aws.push` how does one specify the remote Unix user on the ElasticBeanstalk EC2 instance to create files as?

Is it possible to change the default user?
Where is the default user specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clarification on the deployment process: there's no git server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. `aws.push` is just a wrapper for the shell command, which creates an archive from your local repository and uploads the archive to Elastic Beanstalk server. It is made for convenience.

The default user on Elastic Beanstalk instances is `ec2-user`, with the same group, `ec2-user`.

You can create your own [groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-groups) and [users](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-users) using instance customization mechanism with `.ebextensions/appname.config`

Syntax:

```
users:
  <name of user>:
    groups:
      - <name of group>
    uid: "<id of the user>"
    homeDir: "<user's home directory>"

groups:
  <name of group>:
  <name of group>:
    gid: "<group id>"
```

Example:

```
users:
  myuser:
    groups:
      - group1
      - group2
    uid: "50"
    homeDir: "/tmp"

groups:
  groupOne:
  groupTwo:
    gid: "45"
```

Additional information on the instance customization can be found in [Customizing the Software on EC2 Instances Running Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html)

Use [commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-commands) to manipulate files/directories on EC2 instance, and [container commands](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands) to manipulate your application files/directories.

```
container_commands:
    10-change-owner:
        command: "chown myuser tmpfile"

    20-change-group:
        command: "chown :mygroup tmpfile"
```

Comment: OK, but how do I make the files pushed with git to ElasticBeanstalk belong to a specific user of my choice instead of "webapp" which seems to be the case by default?
In other words, how do I make use of the users created with `.ebextensions/appname.config` when using `git aws.push`?

Comment: @AlexanderShcheblikin: Updated the answer with further information on users/groups.

Comment: Now my question is: do those chown commands run after each `git aws.push`?

Comment: Whichever configuration you have in ebextensions/app.config, it will be applied on each deployment, aka `git aws.push`. You configure it only once.